# How to ask travis to deploy on npm only when merged on master branch?

Tags: npm, travis-ci

We are configuring a public project on github.
We would like our travis job to run test & build on every PR, and deploy (npm publish) only on accepted MR on master.

We have tried this config but it is not working :

```
language: node_js
node_js: 
  - 10.16.0
before_script:
  - npm run build

deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: "myemail@example.com"
  api_key:
    secure: "our secure key that is irrelevant for this question"
  after_deploy:
    - ./script/updateNpmVersion.sh
  on:
    branch: master
```

And ./script/updateNpmVersion.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull develop
npm version minor
git add package.json
git commit -m "bump npm version"
git push origin develop
```

But it is not working. Deploy is basically never called.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a syntax issue. Your `after_deploy` script should be executed after the `deploy` step is finished. Also, you can try providing a particular repository that should be used for deployment while configuring the `on` key.

Another thing, you might need to grant needed permission to execute your `updateNpmVersion.sh` script. So your final `yml` file should look something like this

```
language: node_js

node_js: 
  - 10.16.0

before_script:
  - npm run build
  - chmod +x ./script/updateNpmVersion.sh

deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: "myemail@example.com"
  api_key:
    secure: "our secure key that is irrelevant for this question"
  on:
    repo: OWNER_NAME/REPO_NAME
    branch: master

after_deploy:
    - ./script/updateNpmVersion.sh
```